# Using navigation.openDrawer in Stack Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, jsx

I am trying to use the navigation prop inside my Stack Navigator to open the drawer when the material icon is clicked. However when I click th button I recieve the error:

**Undefined is not an object (evaluating navigation.openDrawer)**

I am confused as I have passed the navigation prop into the 'App' function. Where am I going wrong here?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import SecondScreen from './src/screens/SecondScreen.js';
import {MaterialIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  
const TheDrawer = () => {
return(
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
  <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} /> 
  <Drawer.Screen name="SecondScreen" component={SecondScreen} /> 
</Drawer.Navigator>
);
  }

const App = ({navigation}) =>{
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Home"component={TheDrawer} 
          options={{headerTitle:
            <View>
            <MaterialIcons
              name='menu' 
              onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} size={28}
            />
            </View>
           }} 
         />
        <Stack.Screen name="SecondScreen" component={SecondScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigation prop only exist inside a Navigator, and different Navigators will have different navigation props (the Stack Navigator navigation will **NOT** have the openDrawer method, for example). I think that what you want to accomplish is this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={({ navigation }) => ({
            headerTitle: (
              <View>
                <MaterialIcons name="menu" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} size={28}/>
              </View>
            ),
          })}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen name="SecondScreen" component={SecondScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Or, if you want the menu button available on every page header:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitle: (
            <View>
              <MaterialIcons name="menu" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} size={28} />
            </View>
          ),
        })}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="SecondScreen" component={SecondScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/

If you need to access more pages inside this two (Home, SecondScreen), you can create it like this:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home1" component={HomeScreen1} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Home2" component={HomeScreen2} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Home3" component={HomeScreen3} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
}
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators